# Is it OK to plug a computer into a shared GFCI outlet?

Tags: electrical

Is it OK to have a computer on the same line as a bathroom GFCI outlet?

Comment: It will not be a problem to have your computer on a GFCI protected outlet. Newer homes the bathroom outlets only go to the bathroom. The GFCI is powered on the line side connections and the other outlets would be powered by connecting to the load side of the GFCI.

Comment: Note however that the GFCI protects only circuits downstream from it (attached to the load side). If the computer's outlet circuit branches off the line upstream of the GFCI, the GFCI doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to have the computer plugged into a GFCI, although it may not be preferable. Hard shutdowns, as would be the case if the GFCI tripped (and the computer's receptacle is actually protected as @keshlam's comment suggests), are not the greatest for computers. You may never trip the GFCI, or may only trip it rarely, and this doesn't become an issue. Or, you may have a very sensitive or failing GFCI which trips regularly, putting unnecessary stress on the computer. If you can plug it in elsewhere, that'd be best, but if not it's not a big deal unless your GFCI trips a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Laptop or desktop?

If it's a laptop, there is no issue - if the GCFI trips, the laptop will carry on working off the internal battery.

If a desktop, it will work, but will switch off immediately if the GCFI is tripped for any reason. I would recommend that you get a battery UPS for the computer, so that if the GCFI trips, you get a few minutes to turn the computer off or reset the GCFI.